# Timestamp format

Tags: perl, timestamp

ALL,

I'm about to parse the log file file which has following format:

```
2019-09-06T16:06:36+00:00 some_text
```

Now what I'm curious about is to how to handle the numbers after the `+` sign.
I can split the line by the " " character to get the timestamp, and then split the timestamp by the `T`, but will date/time functions in Perl will understand the `16:06:36+00:00` time? I will need to pass it to `timelocal()` to get an epoch time.

TIA!

Comment: `+00:00` probably represents the same thing as `+0000`, so you could just massage out the final : in the timestamp, and then apply a `Time::Piece->strptime($timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%T%z")` format string.

Comment: @DavidO, thank you. I upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The colon is superfluous, and gets in the way of your parsing. There was a discussion in the Python bug tracker awhile back about parsing timezone offsets with the colon, and it never really got resolved.  The easiest solution is to just get rid of it:

```
use Time::Piece; # A core Perl module.

my $entry = '2019-09-06T16:06:36+00:00 some_text';

my ($timestamp, $text) = split(/\s+/, $entry, 2);
$timestamp =~ s/:(\d+)$/$1/;

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%T%z");
```

In this example we split on the first whitespace to isolate the datestamp, and then substitute away the final colon. So `$timestamp` will now contain:

```
2019-09-06T16:06:36+0000
```

...and that is a timestamp that `strptime` can understand, given the appropriate format string.

Comment: Re "*The colon is superfluous*", Well, it is required by RFC3339 and ISO8601, but I suppose you mean it doesn't convey any additional information.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an RFC3339 timestamp. As such, you could use [DateTime::Format::RFC3339](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::RFC3339).

```
use DateTime::Format::RFC3339 qw( );

my ($dt_str) = split ' ', '2019-09-06T16:06:36+00:00 some text';

my $format = DateTime::Format::RFC3339->new;
my $dt = $format->parse_datetime($dt_str);
my $epoch = $dt->epoch;
```

What you have is an ISO8601 timestamp. As such, you could use [DateTime::Format::ISO8601](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::ISO8601).

```
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601 qw( );

my ($dt_str) = split ' ', '2019-09-06T16:06:36+00:00 some text';

my $format = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->new;
my $dt = $format->parse_datetime($dt_str);
my $epoch = $dt->epoch;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment)'s from_string constructor recognizes this ISO8601 format, even if the colon is present.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Moment;

my $line = '2019-09-06T16:06:36+00:00 some_text';
my ($ts, $rest) = split ' ', $line, 2; # single space is a special case for split()
my $moment = Time::Moment->from_string($ts);
my $epoch = $moment->epoch;
```

The option `lenient => 1` may be needed if the format will be mixed (for example colons in the offset but not the time).

Comment: thank you for the answer. My understanding is that `Time::Moment` is not a standard module. Unfortunately I'm in a very restrictive environment and will not be able to install anything extra.

Comment: @Igor, Not so. If you can install code from SO, you can install code from CPAN